# Trap Syntax Error During Compile

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am setting a list box row source conditionally based on a value:

If MyValue = "" then
   Me.MyList.RowSource = "SELECT...
   FROM...
   RIGHT JOIN...
   GROUP BY...
   ORDER BY...
Else
   Me.MyList.RowSource = "SELECT...
   FROM...
   RIGHT JOIN...
   GROUP BY...
   **HAVING MyValue**
   ORDER BY...
End if

Where MyValue is some criteria for the HAVING part.
This works fine as long as MyValue is not "" (blank).  However during compile, I get a Microsoft Access error:  "Syntax error on HAVING clause."  During runtime, the "else" with HAVING does not occur so no error there.  How can I avoid or trap the "Syntax error on HAVING clause." during compile?  The usual "On error..." does not trap during compile.

Thanks.

Comment: The VBA compiler doesn't show syntax errors in SQL strings. You should show us your *actual* code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't go so far as to insert your code into the listbox field and check the outcome.  But, some good practices will help you trouble shoot this.

```
Dim strRowSourceSQL as String

strRowSourceSQL  = "SELECT ... FROM ... RIGHT JOIN ..."

If MyValue = "" then
    strRowSourceSQL = strRowSourceSQL & "MORE SQL HERE"
else
    strRowSourceSQL = strRowSourceSQL & "DIFFERENT SQL HERE"
end if

Me.MyList.RowSource = strRowSourceSQL
```

This arrangement will let you inspect `strRowSourceSQL`.  Set a break point and...

```
Debug.Print strRowSourceSQL
```

Once you have that, drop into the Query editor and fix what's wrong.  Also, follow [these principles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/122139).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I found the problem.

It turned out that I had a left-over query definition in the **Property Sheet** for the list box that had the offending HAVING clause.  When I removed the definition from the Property Sheet, the form opened without the annoying syntax error.  The vba code I included in my original post was just fine.